# Interpolate in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I am rails developer and new to django. Is there anyway to interpolate like in rails ??

`<a href="{% url upload-csv %}"` works fine but

This doesnt work:
`{% if request.path ==  "url upload-csv" %}class="selected"  {% endif %}`
in rails i wud hav  `request.path ==  "#{url upload-csv}"`

My code is

`<a href="{% url upload-csv %}"  {% if request.path ==  "url upload-csv" %}class="selected"  {% endif %} ><span>Upload CSV</span></a>`"
"/upload-csv/"

Comment: django templates by design don't allow complex logic.  Do it in the view, or if it is ajax, do it with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "as" statement in your url template tag to make it usable as a local variable

```
{% url upload-csv as the_url %}
```

Then you may use `the_url`:

```
<a href="{{ the_url }}" {% if request.path == the_url %}class="selected" {% endif %} ><span>Upload CSV</span></a>
```

But I see no easy way to interpolate complex cases...

If it's too complex, it should be computed in the view...